# Working together ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

How can I use a code in asp.net 4.0 which is coded in asp.net 2.0? 
I use IIS 7.0.

When I struggle to use it, I get error:

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

(targetFramework is in the web.config.)

Comment: What do you mean "a code" - a code snippet e.g. a single class, an assembly, a whole web application? Where is targetFramework in what you're trying to run - is that an attribute in web.config?

Comment: yes it is an attribute in web.config..

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the application in an application pool that is set up to use framework 4.0.

Each application pool can only use one version of the framework, so if you have 2.0 and 4.0 applications on the server, they need to run in separate application pools.